# Making an Image into a Lettrine

Tags: color, small-caps, lettrine, shapes, drop-cap

In the MWE

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum}
\setlength{\textwidth}{12cm}
%\renewcommand{\LettrineTextFont}{\normalfont}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\Large

\lettrine[
    lines=3,
    lraise=0.1,
    findent=.5em,loversize=0.42,
    image=true]{example-image}{\textbf{in small caps}} \lipsum[13]
\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like: (1) To add an appropriate-sized colored (red) letter to the image; (2) I would like to render the words "in small caps" ---in small-caps; and, if possible, I would like to depict the image in something other form than a rectangle---perhaps and oval.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Note: You need `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` to make possible for `\textsc` combine with `\textbf`. As @Cicada's comment, instead you could use some font package if you using `pdflatex` such as `\usepackage{libertinus}` or use `\usepackage{fontspec}\setmainfont{some ttf\.otf font}` if you use `xelatex` or `lualatex`.

I get rid of `lettrine` package. And I define two new macros to achieve this using `tikz` and `wrapfig` package. You could fully customize the style of your image, letter, position, ellipse y radius, color, drop lines number...etc. See the exmaple in code. The `\mydpletter` macro have following syntax:

> %\mydpletter[vertical pos]{Drop lines num}{ellipse y radius}{Scale font size}{Drop letter}{image}{Append text}{Par contents}

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum}
\setlength{\textwidth}{12cm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\newcommand{\addstuff}[3]{\tikz[remember picture]{
#1
\node[inner sep=0pt](current content){#3};
#2
}}
\newcommand{\mydpletter}[8][-5pt]{%
\begin{wrapfigure}[#2]{l}{0.2\linewidth}
\vspace{#1}
\addstuff{
\clip (0,0) ellipse [x radius=0.5\linewidth, y radius=#3];
}{
\node [inner sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\scalebox{#4}{#5}};
}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{#6}}
\end{wrapfigure}
{\noindent\hbox{\textsc{\textbf{#7 }}}#8\par}
}

%\mydpletter[vertical pos]{Drop lines num}{ellipse y radius}{Scale font size}{Drop letter}{image}{Append text}{Par contents}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\Large
\mydpletter[-2pt]{3}{25pt}{4}{\color{red!70}A}{example-image-plain}{In Small Caps}{\lipsum[1]}
\mydpletter[-12pt]{6}{50pt}{6}{\color{blue!70}B}{example-image-9x16}{In Small Caps}{\lipsum[2]}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Very nice! Unrelated: T1 fonts are 8-bit and from before Unicode; I use utf8 file format and .ttf\.otf fonts for small caps: `%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}\usepackage{fontspec}\setmainfont{Noto Serif}`

Comment: @Cicada Yes, but if pdflatex, also should inlcude some font package to support the combine, such as `\usepackage{libertinus}`

Comment: Many thanks for your comprehensive answer.